# When running 2 http AsyncTasks in parallel sometimes results are exchanged

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a strange problem in my application.

I have an activity that fetches 2 or 3 things in parallel using AsyncTasks

When I simply do the following

```
new getMessages().execute("someID");
new getNotifications().execute("someID");
```

and the both AsyncTasks has code as follows:

(Both of them are identical except that the URL requested by each method is different).

**Notice: I modified this code a little bit just to remove any unneeded extras like extra parameters sent in the http request**

```
// in the other Async task "notifications" is changed with  "messages"
    public class getNotifications extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        Integer verified = 0;

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                    // getRequestsCount just perfomrs http request and grabs JSON data
            String result = getRequestsCount(args[0] , "notifications");
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    // This is just a method that handles the result 
                    // When I log result I found that results are exchanged.
            displayResults(result);
        }

    }
public String getRequestsCount(String id, String type){

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new

        HttpPost(GlobalSettings.apiURL + "/getcount/" + type );

Log.i("will contact",GlobalSettings.apiURL + "/getcount/" + type);


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String responseMessage = reader.readLine().toString().trim();

 // Response is always 1 line of JSON data

Log.i("Response for "+type,responseMessage);
return responseMessage;

}
```

Now my problem is that sometimes results are exchanged.

i.e. getMessages recives the JSON data requested from getNotifications
and vice versa.

Comment: Do you mean that although you call execute() on getMessages first and then and getNotifications, you see the results come back in inversed order? Or have you actually added logging to your doInBackground() that prints the request and immediately after that the response (to check if your getRequestsCount() method is returning the correct result)?

Comment: I did both, Logging and checking the results of getMessages and getNotifications, and actually what happens is that the 1st http response received goes to the 1st executed AsyncTask and the 2nd one goes to the 2nd. and my http request object and params are completely local variables/instances inside the method getRequest.

Comment: When I use threads instead of AsyncTasks such issue doesn't happen is there a point behind that ??

Comment: Can you provide us the `displayResults`code? I mean, show us how do you see that the results are exchanged.

Comment: I added the http request code used

Comment: and you are saying that the Log.i("Response for "+type,responseMessage) line prints you a log saying something like "Response for notifications", "something that is clearly a messages response"? Or are you just puzzled by the fact that although you call getMessages.execute() first and getNotifications.execute() afterwards, you get the results back in inverted order (but the reply is linked correctly to the request). I really hope it is the latter, because if you call httpclient.execute() you would hope you get the correct response back. Somebody else would have had this problem then as well?

Comment: As @baske said, if is the first case, could be simply a sync problem of the Log class. Try this: `public synchronized void logMsg(String type, String responseMessage) {
  Log.i("Response for "+type,responseMessage);
 }`

Comment: No, if it is the first case that indeed something would be wrong, since then it is not a problem with out-of-order logging (either because the logging is not flushing in a way you would expect or because the asynctasks just finish in different order) but really a wrong reply to your http request. I do think this is unlikely though, because these classes are widely used and somebody else would have surely experienced the same issues. I just think it is the 2 asynctasks truly running in parallel (depending a bit on your Android version) and finishing in inversed order.

Comment: Look this is what I get:
"Response for Messages: (JSON OF NOTIFICATIONS)."
"Response for Notifications (JSON OF MESSAGES).", but not always it happens only sometimes you can say 70% of the time I get correct response but 30% of the time I get response for different HTTP requests./// And I don't care about the Sequence as long as the response is corresponding to the request not to other request

Comment: I doubt something (so much) which is http response is cached or buffered somehow so sometimes the response is server from buffer or from cache directly without correct checks.

Comment: Hmm I am afraid I cannot help you then, Shehabox. Seems to me like very strange behavior indeed.